# The system preference panes will not load

Tags: preferences, macos

When I open **System Preferences** and click on an item it says 'Loading Users & Groups' at the top of the window, but will not load the pane.

I've tried deleting the property list file:

```
 /library/preferences/com.apple.systempreference.plist
```

I also tried clearing the PRAM and booting in Safe Mode.

Comment: I'm adding the text "Could not load Time Machine preference pane.", copied verbatim from the sheet I see on System Preferences when this happens to me.  I hope that will help people searching.

Comment: I can't remember why this post popped up, probably in the review queues for a first post and I saw the original question had a typo, I did consider removing the stuff you did but felt light touch was better. @ankii

Comment: @unknowndomain Okay I guess it was https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/381022/313842 .. nvm I thought you bumped it

Comment: No worries @ankii!

Comment: The same happened to me with software update, I got the message "Could not load Software Update preference pane." ... check my answer below, which has always helped so far.

Comment: I've tried everything mentioned here with no luck. The only thing that worked for me was to use the migration assistant and restore the System files and settings of an older time machine backup. Restoring from time machine directly doesn't work because the system is in use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked in the console? Maybe you'll find some error messages there which can narrow the problem down.
You can view log files in Console, located in /Applications/Utilities.

Have you tried to check (and maybe repair) the file rights. You can do this with disk utility.

[About Disk Utility's Repair Disk Permissions feature](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT1452?viewlocale=en_US)

Comment: yes rean disk utility first fixed all sorts of problems there gonna look at console now

Comment: logs says "PreferencePanes folder is missing" I guess that can't be fixed without re install ?

Comment: To be honest i am not sure. Haven't tried to delete my prefs folder :). Maybe you can use Time Machine to restore the folder?

Comment: ha good point , doubt they had time machine running but thats a good thing to try thanks for your help

Comment: just checked: directory for system PrefPanes is : /System/Library/PreferencePanes

Comment: After Yosemite, we no longer have Repair Disk Permissions.

Comment: This does not usually work, but today, the problem did go away when I quit System Preferences and tried again.  El Capitan 10.11.6 on a MacBook (13-inch, Early 2009).

Answer (score 18):

Sometimes it's just enough to **quit the *System Preferences* app**. Check if the process was ended well, i.e. use Activity Monitor (also to quit "System Preferences" app). In my recent case it was not necessary to force quit, just select the process and quit was enough.

Alternatively Force Quit if *System Preferences* is open and in the Doc, just do a secondary click on the System Preferences icon, hit *[alt]* key "Quit" will change got "**Force Quit**" and click that.

After restarting the app the preference pane (in my case time machine pane) could be loaded as expected.

Lately it happened, that the described method didn't work, after force quit I still couldn't open the preference pane. I found that **waiting a little** (few minutes) before reopening helped, because when I was not able to reopen the pane I searched for a different solution, coming back to System Preferences – without doing anything else – was able to open the desired pane.

Answer (score 3):

Boot in single user mode (Hold down SHIFT key right after hitting the power button until the Apple Logo appears), Login, Launch System Preferences, Load the Preferences Pane that is not working, Restart Mac OS X.  That worked for me when nothing else did.

Comment: Shift is actually Safe Mode, but the rest is certainly worth a try.

Comment: Edited to explain single-user mode based on content from Mac Help.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is just simply open every pane from the left upper corner to the right lower corner. After that, the "security and privacy" pane resume normal.

No need for even a reboot.

Answer (score -1):

Restart, Hold Shift key right after your screen shut down to run safe mode, go to display preferences again to check if is can be opened, and then restart -> Done, I tried and it worked on OS 10.12.3. 
p/s: I found out this solution of Claeton in this post. Thanks a lot!

Comment: While I was able to get back into the preference panel the issue returned again but a few moments later I tried and was able to open Time Machine Preferences. So I can't say this is a resolution.